# SQLite with .Net: Datareader Close Method is too slow

Tags: .net, sqlite, datareader

I'm have a batch proccess that reads from many datareaders.

When I finished with de datareader I call the close() method.

This is too slow. If I don´t close the data reader, the application runs in 0.4ms
If I close the datareader, the application runs in 26 seconds.

Does anybody has a tip in how to solve this problem?

There are many datareaders in sub routines. I´m afraid that not closing them I will keep trash in memory.

Comment: Any more context here? Dd you read all the data? Could it be discarding the 2 million other rows you didn't read? Is there a transaction involved?

Comment: There is no transacion involved. with sql server i read that i can call Cancel method for the command object before call close. that increase speed, but did not work for sqlite. the result set is about 1000 rows. I read it all befor call close. I don´t think is much considering the size off all I have.

Comment: Are you reading only the first few rows from the data readers you may benifit by putting a `top` in your query.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

The Method Close of the Datareader was slow because it was inside a try-catch.
I remove de try-catch and it´s ok now.